# SwiftUI Core Data Crashing on a MacOS app with NavigationView

Tags: macos, core-data, swiftui

I've written a small app which uses Core Data along with SwiftUI to make a basic note taker app for old adventure games. I'm using a NavigationView in a master/detail configuration where the master list is the list of people's names that the notes are for (this is designed for games like Tex Murphy), and clicking on them causes the detail view to display some textFields to change details.

The bug I'm hitting is if I have a textfield affecting the person's name. Occasionally when I change the name, it causes the app to crash with: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). This crash is relatively random where it might happen around 10% of the time. If I make the master view instead show any other text than the person's name, then it doesn't crash. Ensuring the name is changed only on the master thread doesn't have any effect, so I don't think it's a thread safety issue. Unfortunately the debugger isn't particularly useful here as I can't isolate when it's crashing.

Any ideas?

Here's the code for changing the person's name:

```
                    TextField("Enter name", text: $name) {
                        self.person.name = self.name
                        do {
                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
```

Where person is the person object send across via the navigationView, and name is a state value (since I'm not sure how to have the textfield change the person's name directly)

Comment: which version of Xcode do you use? there are some problems with **NavigationView** in new 11.3 version (there were questions about it today). If you use the latest version, m.b. better to try your code only in main view (without **NavigationView**) and check for errors to exclude the influence of **NavigationView**

Comment: Weirdly, when I've upgraded to the latest version, this has stopped crashing. Instead it's giving an error (which I'll post once I'm on my laptop later) but continuing to run.